# fopen function in mfc c++

Tags: c++, mfc, fopen

this is previously asked question by me and I would like some new input on this matter.

I've created a program to read a pre-existing text file that is constantly being updated every few millisecond (real time logger) and lastly grabbing certain lines from the text file and printing it out on a .csv file. This is a program requested by my client.

I have tested this out with a copy of the text file on my computer and my colleagues computer and it seems to work absolutely fine but when it comes to the clients computer using the file that is constantly being updated, it doesn't print anything out on a csv (no csv is created).

My question is,

Will there be a possibility of the real time logger returning an empty file to me as it is constantly being used by a separate program that updates it every millisecond?

Possibly using this:-

```
fopen(RealTimeLogger, "w")
```

Since it is constantly being opened and used by the separate program does that affect my

```
fopen(RealTimeLogger, "r+t")
```

function call to read the text file?

Comment: You should simulate the problem. Write a program that writes to a file frequently and try to open that file. Check for fopen errors, read errors, read count=0, etc. Also I doubt you can fopen(...,'w') the file as the writing program 'owns' the file. Also try 'open', not fopen, bit closer to the OS, possibly a bit faster.

Comment: hmmm, i get what you are saying. What if i first copy the instance of the file being written and then paste it somewhere and continuing reading the copied file. Once i am done with it ill delete the file. and then it goes on in a circle the next time i am suppose to read the file again. will that work?

Comment: You could also use the Win32 API `CreateFile` documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) with the appropriate `ShareMode` flags. However, you might have to modify the program writing the file as well.

Comment: Often, when an app is writing a file it will block all other attempts to read and write the file. Therefore, if on the client machine it's taking longer to write each log line than on your test machines it may mean that the log file is almost continually locked against reading.

Comment: Ive tested this theory by creating just two simple program. one to write into a file recursively until i call it to stop and another to try to read the file and print it out to a csv. Both processes of doing it normally or even copying and pasting the file failed as it will always be at 0kb unless fclose is called in and I see no way of moving past this point unless i rewrite the code for writing the file. Any ideas or there is simply no way